# Drools generate filters on rule dinamically

Tags: drools

New with JBoss Drools :)

I'm working on a PoC where there's a rule where one or multiple filters can exist. I'm using a template to generate that rule dynamically.

```
template header

effectiveDate
expirationDate
rule
totalPriceValue

package test.template;
import  test.domain.ProductDiscountRequest;

template "value discount template"

rule "Value discount on customer_@{row.rowNumber}"
    date-effective "@{effectiveDate}"
    date-expires   "@{expirationDate}"
    when
        requestObject : ProductDiscountRequest(@{rule} && totalPrice > @{totalPriceValue});
    then
        requestObject.addDiscount(5.0d);
end

end template
```

This template, with the correct input, generates a rule like

```
package test.template;
import  test.domain.ProductDiscountRequest;

rule "Value discount on customer_0"
    date-effective "25-Jun-2022 16:00"
    date-expires   "26-Jun-2030 8:00"
    when
        requestObject : ProductDiscountRequest(customer == 'TestCustomer' && totalPrice > 30);
    then
        requestObject.addDiscount(5.0d);
end
```

There are multiple filters available and they can also be combined, so **customer == 'TestCustomer'** can also be **customer == 'TestCustomer' && custGroup == "TestGroup"** and so forth.
I see 3 solutions:

1. Generate the filtering part in the code and only insert it
2. Create distinct rules per number of filters (1 rule for 1 filter, 1 rule for 2 filters etc)
3. Send the filters to the template and generate it there directly

I tried some things but I couldn't get #3 to work. Supposing that there's a list of filters, how do I iterate over it and concatenate it to a full condition?

I'm open to other ideas to make this better.

Comment: It's JBoss Drools, not Apache. I'm also really unclear about what you're trying to do ... can you show the csv data you're trying to run against your rule template that isn't generating what you need?

Comment: I'm not generating the rule from the template in the code, not using a csv.

Comment: The main point is that @{rule} must be flexible. It can have one condition, like in the example "customer == 'TestCustomer'", or multiple, like "customer == 'TestCustomer' && custGroup == 'TestGroup'". I can build the rule content in the code but I would like to send a list of conditions and concatenate them together with ' && ' in the drl file. I don't know if it's possible or even a good idea.

Comment: It's not a good idea.